# Save Image from Browser to iOs and Android Photo Gallery

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-chrome, safari

I am trying to figure out a way to create a "save the image" button on a page in either safari or chrome on mobile devices. When the user taps on the "save the image" button, he/she can save the image next to or on the button to the local photo gallery of the phone.

I'm familiar with JavaScript but know very little about iOS & Android. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks!